# css selectors don't include children

Tags: css

I have the below html

```
<ul><li><a href="home/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news/">News</a></li>
    <li class="subnav"><a href="about/">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="contact/">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this css.

```
ul > .subnav a {}
.subnav a {}
```

I want to apply this css only to the li containing 'about' not the child li 'contact'.

Can this be done without adding additional style to the child?
eg

```
.subnav li a {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
ul > .subnav > a
```

or even just

```
ul > .subnav
```

Comment: ul > .subnav > was exactly what I was after!